# Imagick Failed to read the file PDF

Tags: php, pdf, imagick

I'm using Imagick and trying to convert a pdf to a png. It fails. My error_log says "Failed to read the file".

[image: Php info]

Example code:

```
$fileone =  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/' . 'test.pdf';
$image = new Imagick($fileone);
$image->readImage($fileone);
$image->thumbnailImage(300, 0);
echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,' .  base64_encode($image->getimageblob())  . '" />';
```

Thoughts?

Comment: I assume you have installed `ghostscript`?

Comment: Yeah I reinstalled and reset the server just to be safe.

Comment: @Jeremy, have you solve your problem? Have same.

Comment: @oleg Yeah, my solution was to by pass imagick entirely for PDFs and just use ghostscript.

Answer (score 6):

You need to install ghostscript

```
sudo apt-get install ghostscript
```

Answer (score 2):

I would first use `realpath()` to check your file path and then see if the file is readable.

```
$fileone = realpath('test.pdf');

if (!is_readable($fileone)) {
    echo 'file not readable';
}
```

Then if it is a multiple page pdf try this

```
$image = new Imagick($fileone.'[0]');
```

Comment: Are you running this script locally through something like eg. MAMP or on a server?

Comment: Yeah it's coming through MAMP.  Converting from PNG's or JPEG's work just fine. It just has fit's with pdfs.

Comment: maybe try manually re-installing imagick https://github.com/delphian/drupal-convert-file/wiki/Installing-ImageMagick-on-Mac-OSX-for-PHP-and-MAMP

Comment: Yeah I tried that. It didn't work. Is there something else that could be wrong?

Comment: also try `$image = new Imagick($fileone.'[0]');` if it is a multiple page pdf